# What to do about users that use two fingers to swipe?

Tags: usability, user-behavior, swipe, zooming

I am wondering if you guys have any solutions for a problem I am consistently seeing on our mobile site. We signed up for Inspectlet a couple months ago and something that I see from several mobile and tablet users is they are using two fingers to swipe up and down.

Now this would not be a problem if I was to disable zoom functionality but because it is not disabled they will zoom in when they swipe and can not seem to figure out how to zoom out again. The major demographic of our website are users 45 years old and up, which could attribute to some of the things I am seeing.

I have been reading and the general consensus seems to be NOT to disable zoom, which I agree because there are some people that use the zoom to check out our images.

Hoping someone might have some suggestions for me...

Comment: Does the site present a mix of elements, some of which users might want to zoom - such as a map?

Comment: It is mostly text, product images and icons along with some buttons, nothing out of the ordinary. We do not have a map on the site. The images are clickable to either go to the product page or blow up into a lightbox. When I see people zoom they are zooming in on the images of the products on the product category pages (these are the people that know how to zoom back out).

Comment: A 2 finger swipe shouldn't zoom because the distance between the fingers doesn't change?

Comment: I agree with jamesryan.  A 2 finger swipe isn't the problem.  You might want to reinterpret the data you are getting.

Comment: @JamesRyan I think that is the case for most users, but there are still some where the distance does change, although not intentional. If someone has arthritis or another ailment that affects finger dexterity I can imagine the two fingers are bound to move apart occasionally.

Comment: @Yamaha32088 As an over 45 year old with arthritic hands, the last thing my fingers do is unwittingly drift apart occasionally. Though 2 of them are being brandished apart in response to you ageist remarks.

Comment: This seems odd. Are you sure the service you are using is reporting things correctly? Is the two finger swipe perhaps an OS-level interaction rather than an interaction with your own particular app?

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing anything about your app, the best solution I can think of, is introducing a brief on-boarding that includes instructions on swiping with one finger to use the app (with an accompanying visual example).

I'd be interested to know where they're getting the idea that two fingers is for swipe; maybe they're laptop users having a hard time transitioning. In that case, a brief on-boarding would really help.

Alternately: How prevalent is the behaviour? Does the user repeat it after the first mistake, or learn from their mistake? I know I occasionally forget that macbook trackpad gestures are different to iphone, and swipe incorrectly, finding myself in zoom. But I immediately realise my mistake, and carry on just fine.